# How to use a Sub procedure in another Sub procedure without opening the target Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, split

my problem is that a computer where the Excel file is is too large and the machine cannot handle it, so I have a macro to divide the data of a file into sub files, so I could get the information from that large file without opening it, the split macro is functional on its own, but I'm trying to run the macro without opening the target file (by running the macro on a blank workbook) and it runs with no results.

```
Option Explicit

Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String)
 Dim iFilenum As Long
 Dim iErr As Long
 On Error Resume Next
 iFilenum = FreeFile()
 Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum
 Close iFilenum
 iErr = Err
 On Error GoTo 0
 Select Case iErr
 Case 0: IsFileOpen = False
 Case 70: IsFileOpen = True
 Case Else: Error iErr
 End Select
End Function

Sub ModificarArchivo()

Dim data_sh As Worksheet
Set data_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Dim Archive As Application
Dim Archivename As String

Set Archive = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With Archive
    Archivename = data_sh.Range("E14").Value
    
        If IsFileOpen(Archivename) Then
        '
        Else
            With .Workbooks.Open(Archivename)
                split_excel
           
            End With
        End If
    .Quit
End With
End Sub

Sub split_excel()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Hoja con los datos
Dim datos_sh As Worksheet
Set datos_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'Hoja con los ajustes
Dim ajustes_sh As Worksheet
Set ajustes_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
'Se definen nuevas libros de excel
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet
'Se recorre la columna deseada y creara unicos para categorizar
ajustes_sh.Range("A:A").Clear
datos_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
datos_sh.Range("B2:B").Copy ajustes_sh.Range("A1")
ajustes_sh.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
'Selecciona la columna para filtrar y copiar los datos en una nueva hoja
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To Application.CountA(ajustes_sh.Range("A:A"))
    datos_sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, ajustes_sh.Range("A" & i).Value
    Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
    Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
    datos_sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy nsh.Range("A1")
    nsh.UsedRange.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15
    nsh.UsedRange.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
'Funcion de guardado de las hojas de calculo
    nwb.SaveAs ajustes_sh.Range("H6").Value & "/" & ajustes_sh.Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsx"
    nwb.Close False
    data_sh.AutoFilterMode = False
Next i
ajustes_sh.Range("A:A").Clear
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

`data_sh.Range("E14").Value`
is the path of the target archive, same with
`nwb.SaveAs ajustes_sh.Range("H6").Value`
it is the path where the split data will save.

Comment: If it is a blank workbook then what is in E14 : Archivename = data_sh.Range("E14").Value

Comment: In E14 i put the path of the target archive, read above.

Comment: data_sh.Range("E14").Value is the path of the target archive, same with nwb.SaveAs ajustes_sh.Range("H6").Value it is the path where the split data will save.

Comment: Blank workbook in the sense that is not a heavy archive, just has two paths in the cells.

Comment: Make sure you return true or false when there is an error.

Comment: `split_excel` has no connection/context from the `With` block you call it from: it always targets `ThisWorkbook`